# what is the best solution for restful authentication in laravel?

Tags: rest, laravel, oauth, restful-authentication

I am implementing back-end of a mobile app by Laravel.
current requirement is implementing a stateless solution for authenticating users through restful API.
after that I should find a way to allow users to register and login with their Google and Facebook accounts.
I want to find a stable solution that fit with both of these problem if it is possible.

I know these library exists for laravel but I want an experienced advice to choose best of them:
adamwathan/eloquent-oauth (it seems it is the best fit for my requirements but it is not stable yet)
artdarek/oauth-4-laravel
jenssegers/laravel-oauth
kalley/laravel-oauth-client
Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib
dschniepp/Laravel-OAuth2-Server

Comment: OAuth 2.0 is the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This package fits with the requirements:
https://github.com/tappleby/laravel-auth-token

Answer (score 0):

Use oAuth2. There's a few decent packages out there. IMO this is your best bet: https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel